# What was the rational to make None a default return value in python instead of checking it as it is done to uninitialized variables

Tags: python, theory

In Python you can declare a function that doesn't explicitly return a value. For example, you can write:

```
def launch_aborted():
    call_KimJongUn()
    # oops we forget to return a value
```

and then successfully use it in an if statement, for example:

```
if not launch_aborted():
    launch_ballistic_missile()
```

In a similar situation, the use of uninitialized variables, Python recognizes an error and throws an exception. Python doesn't treat uninitialized variables as *None by default* as it does with function return value.

```
# if the variable launch_aborted wasn't assigned yet
# interpreter throws NameError or UnboundLocalError here
if not launch_aborted:
    # this code will not be exceuted
    launch_ballistic_missile()
```

This behavior masks errors. If a function has a bug in its declaration, if not all its control paths return a value, it will be difficult to find this bug because by default it returns None and None is also a valid value in boolean expressions and assignments.

I am looking for any justification of this design decision other than simplicity of implementation. I understand that it would need additional check in a caller to track this error and it may degrade performance slightly, but this doesn't look like a reasonable argument here, the similar check for a variable state has also introduce a delay.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it is an option to compare to True/False instead of a bare `if`.

Comment: @RecencyEffect lets slightly change the example then: `if launch_aborted() == True: abort() else: launch_ballistic_missile()` and voila the missile is launched and compare to `True` didn't save the planet

Comment: I think it's just the nature of dynamically typed languages. How would you tell Python that a function returns nothing (like `void xyz()` in C) versus something? Some dynamically-typed languages will return the value of the last expression, but that's error-prone too. Another option would be to force all functions to have a return statement, but that would make for some really tedious code (at least in some cases).

Comment: @Blurp this can be checked by returning a flag from a function along with return value; or by calling it with some flag set if its result is intended to be used in expression and the return instruction will check and throw exception if needed. It needs to be implemented at a very low level of interpretation process and hidden from the programmer. And of course it will break currently running programs, it must had been implemented in early versions of the language or in the next major version. Technically it was possible and not very difficult.

Comment: _Of course_ they could have designed the language some other way, but they didn't, probably because it doesn't fit with the language's dynamic nature. Note that many other dynamically-typed languages do something similar (JavaScript returns `undefined`; Ruby returns the value of the last expression or `nil`).

Comment: @Blurp the JavaScript also lack this check. This is part of a reason why I asked the question. May be I missed something. It doesn't break the dynamic nature of the language, it is exactly the same as uninitialized variables usage. Variables aren't None by default, and the return values shouldn't be None by default as well. These checks just require some effort from the interpreter and introduce some overhead.

Comment: Then compare with `is not False`. Still has downsides, but in a sense it becomes the programmer's responsibility to use the correct construct, given python's lack of typing as blurp pointed out.

Comment: Python, like many other languages, does not follow Fortran and Pascal in making a distinction between `subroutine`s (Fortran's keyword) or `procedure`s (Pascal's keyword), on the one hand, and functions, on the other. In Python, a "procedure" is simply a function that doesn't return a value. Your proposal amounts to saying that Python should require all functions to return a value explicitly, in which case the language would have only functions and no procedures. This is counterintuitive for functions like `print` that cannot be said to return any sensible value.

Comment: @BoarGules I don't propose to make functions always return a value. I am perfectly fine with the function that don't return a value, I am also fine with the function that only return a value sometimes, but interpreter should throw an exception if an undefined function return value is used in expression afterwards. In example above it would be ok to just call the function `launch_aborted()`, but it is not ok to use in expression its return value, that wasn't explicitly provided by the function. This of course can be done and checked dynamically in runtime.

Comment: Also the `return` operator with no argument shouldn't be treated as `return None` by default.

Comment: Umm, that would amount to adding a new fundamental type `Undefined` to the language. I think the hidden control variable you propose would be regarded as un-Pythonic ("explicit is better than implicit"). SO isn't really the place to make this proposal. The Python community is fairly open to ideas of this kind, but you would need to write a PEP (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/).

Comment: @BoarGules no, the other *meta none* type is ugly. Uninitialized variables don't have any special type, they are just tracked as such. I've asked Guido in mail, he said that he disagree that function shouldn't return None by default with no explanation. Python community is rather close to ideas, its just a Guido personal fan army. PEPs are either written and blessed by him or got ignored. There are many other imperfections in the language like mutable default arguments. They aren't fixed and aren't recognized as a bug to not drop a shadow on the master who coded this bug many years ago.

Comment: @BoarGules but I may be wrong and None default return value is important somewhere. May be in some weird decorator definition it is very useful and can't be avoided. That is why I asked the question. Probably someone can point it out.

Comment: @BoarGules also, implicit None default return value actually violates the "explicit is better than implicit" principle, if the return value wasn't explicitly provided by a function it shouldn't be implicitly assumed to be None

Comment: For a decision as old as this one? Probably some combination of implementation convenience and Guido's whims at the time. It's a lot easier to throw a NameError/UnboundLocalError on any attempt to read an uninitialized variable than to throw an error when you try to actually do something with a nonexistent return value, because with the variable, you don't have to wait for the "do something" part. `uninitialized_variable` on its own line is an error, but `func_that_returns_nothing()` needs to not throw anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in mitigating this problem for yourself, check out [type annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). They let you specify explicitly whether your functions can return None or not, and type checkers like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) can then tell you whether your code might break if they do.